# Последовательное выполнение функций при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как заставить 3 функции сработать одновременно когда произойдет нажатие на button ? Причем нажатие будет только одно, а не для каждой функции.
То есть при нажатии на button, должна выстрелить первая функция, и все следующие после нее так же должны активироваться с запуском таймаута. Пример:

```js
function ex1() {
   document.getElementById('firstArrow').style.display='inline';
   
}
setTimeout(ex1,2000);
function ex2() {
   document.getElementById('secondArrow').style.display='inline';
}
setTimeout(ex2,4000);
function ex3() {
   document.getElementById('thirdArrow').style.display='inline';
}
setTimeout(ex3,6000);
```

```css
.checkmark-circle {

  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  
}
.checkmark-circle .background {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2196f3;
  position: relative;
    
}
.checkmark-circle .checkmark {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.checkmark-circle .checkmark.draw:after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 100ms;
  -moz-animation-delay: 100ms;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-name: checkmark;
  -moz-animation-name: checkmark;
  animation-name: checkmark;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.checkmark-circle .checkmark:after {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 25px;
  width: 27.5px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 2.5px !important;
  content: '';
  left: 3px;
  top: 26px;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.w3-button {width:160px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>

  <p><button class="w3-button w3-deep-orange">Deep Orange</button></p>

<div class="checkmark-circle"  id="firstArrow" style="display:none">
   <div class="background"></div>
   <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="secondArrow" style="display:none">
   <div class="background"></div>
   <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="thirdArrow" style="display:none">
   <div class="background"></div>
   <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```js
function ex(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ex('firstArrow');
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    ex('secondArrow');
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    ex('thirdArrow');
  }, 6000);
});
```

```css
.checkmark-circle {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.checkmark-circle .background {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2196f3;
  position: relative;
}

.checkmark-circle .checkmark {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkmark-circle .checkmark.draw:after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 100ms;
  -moz-animation-delay: 100ms;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-name: checkmark;
  -moz-animation-name: checkmark;
  animation-name: checkmark;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.checkmark-circle .checkmark:after {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 25px;
  width: 27.5px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 2.5px !important;
  content: '';
  left: 3px;
  top: 26px;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.w3-button {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><button class="w3-button w3-deep-orange" id="btn">Deep Orange</button></p>

<div class="checkmark-circle" id="firstArrow">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="secondArrow">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="thirdArrow">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```js
function ex(id) {
  $('#' + id).show();
}

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ex('firstArrow');
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    ex('secondArrow');
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    ex('thirdArrow');
  }, 6000);
});
```

```css
.checkmark-circle {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.checkmark-circle .background {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2196f3;
  position: relative;
}

.checkmark-circle .checkmark {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkmark-circle .checkmark.draw:after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 100ms;
  -moz-animation-delay: 100ms;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-name: checkmark;
  -moz-animation-name: checkmark;
  animation-name: checkmark;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.checkmark-circle .checkmark:after {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 25px;
  width: 27.5px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 2.5px !important;
  content: '';
  left: 3px;
  top: 26px;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.w3-button {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><button class="w3-button w3-deep-orange" id="btn">Deep Orange</button></p>

<div class="checkmark-circle" id="firstArrow">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="secondArrow">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="thirdArrow">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для jQuery ещё можно через `$.click()`, пример: `$('#id').click(() => { /* do something */ })`.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно просто вставить вызов всех трех функций в обработчик события клика.
Исходя из приведенного кода используется jquery, значит можно так:

```
//код сработает при полной загрузке страницы
$(document).ready(function() {
    //получаем по id элемент и добавляем на событие клика обработчик
    $("#firstArrow").click(function() {
        //сюда вставить код, который нужно выполнить по клику
    });
});
```

Comment: Исходя из вышеприведенного кода jquery как раз и не используется. Иначе было бы куда проще :)

Comment: Хотя ссылка на библиотеку есть...